Get WooCommerce order items ACF field values for variable products
I tried in many ways to filter out specific orders from WooCommerce that contain relevant simple & variable products (with ACF information) and then export them via XML to my fulfillment partner.
For that, I am using WP ALL EXPORT PRO and ACF plugins with a custom code:
USED IN XML EDITOR of WP ALL EXPORT PLUGIN
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<orders>
    <!-- BEGIN LOOP -->
    <order>
        <commission>{Bestell ID}</commission>
        <production>2</production>

        <receiver>
            <line1>{Shipping First Name} {Shipping Last Name}</line1>
            <line2>{Shipping Company}</line2>
            <street>{Shipping Address 1}</street>
            <streetnumber>{Shipping Address 2}</streetnumber>
            <country_code>{Shipping Country}</country_code>
            <zip>{Shipping Postcode}</zip>
            <city>{Shipping City}</city>
            <email>{Customer Account Email Address}</email>

        </receiver> 

        <items> 
            [my_get_order_items({Bestell ID})]
        </items>
    </order>
    <!-- END LOOP -->
</orders>

USED IN FUNCTION PHP EDITOR OF WP ALL EXPORT PLUGIN
function my_get_order_items($Bestell_id) {
    // Check if the Bestell ID is valid
    if (!$Bestell_id) {
        return false;
    }
    
    // Fetch the order
    $order = wc_get_order($Bestell_id);
    if (!$order) {
        return false;
    }

    // Initialize the string to store order details
    $order_details = "";

    // Loop through each order item
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item) {
        // Get the product object
        $product = $item->get_product();

        // Skip if there's no product associated with the item
        if (!$product) 
        { continue; }
        
        
        if (!(
strpos($item->get_name(), 'KERAMIKTASSE') !== false ||
strpos($item->get_name(), 'BAUMWOLLTASCHE') !== false ||
strpos($item->get_name(), 'T-SHIRT') !== false))
{ continue; }
        
        $order_details .= "**LT**item**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**ID**GT**" . $product->get_sku() . "**LT**/ID**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**produktname**GT**" . $item->get_name() . "**LT**/produktname**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**amount**GT**" . $item->get_quantity() . "**LT**/amount**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**upload**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'upload', $product->get_id() ) ) . "**LT**/upload**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**size**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'size', $product->get_id() ) ) . "**LT**/size**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**groesse**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'produktgröße', $product->get_id() ) )  . "**LT**/groesse**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**material**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'material', $product->get_id() ) ) . "**LT**/material**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**print**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'print', $product->get_id() ) ) . "**LT**/print**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**variante**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'variante', $product->get_id() ) ) . "**LT**/variante**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**category**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'category', $product->get_id() ) ) . "**LT**/category**GT**";
        
        //add options to the output
        $order_details .= "**LT**Options**GT**";
            $order_details .= "**LT**Option**GT****LT**ID**GT**" . "1996" . "**LT**/ID**GT****LT**Value**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'value_115', $product->get_id() ) ) . "**LT**/Value**GT****LT**/Option**GT**";
        
            $order_details .= "**LT**Option**GT****LT**ID**GT**" . "2489" . "**LT**/ID**GT****LT**Value**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'value_117', $product->get_id() ) ) . "**LT**/Value**GT****LT**/Option**GT**";
        
            $order_details .= "**LT**Option**GT****LT**ID**GT**" . "2056" . "**LT**/ID**GT****LT**Value**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'value_118', $product->get_id() ) ) . "**LT**/Value**GT****LT**/Option**GT**";
        
        $order_details .= "**LT**/Options**GT**";
        
        $order_details .= "**LT**/item**GT**";
        
    }

    return $order_details;
}

This code works well so far and all relevant orders and all relevant products are filtered. The only problem I have is that only the ACF field information for simple products is exported. For variable products all ACF fields remain empty.

How I can finally transfer variable products + ordered product variants via xml – analogue to "simple products"?
How do I have to change my PHP code and/or ACF settings?

First, you should determine if it is a simple or variable product -https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/341803/how-to-get-woocommerce-selected-variation-from-order-object then you should be able to get your data

To solve the issue for your variable products where the ACF fields are empty, it requires using the parent variable product ID with ACF get_field() function, instead of the product variation ID.
Also, there are some unnecessary things in your code.
Try the following PHP replacement code:
function my_get_order_items( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( absint($order_id) ); // Get the WC_Order object
    
    if ( ! is_a($order, 'WC_Order') ) {
        return false; // Exit if not an order
    }
    $order_details = ""; // Initialize variable as string to store order details

    // Loop through order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        if ( ! ( strpos($item->get_name(), 'KERAMIKTASSE') !== false
        || strpos($item->get_name(), 'BAUMWOLLTASCHE') !== false
        || strpos($item->get_name(), 'T-SHIRT') !== false ) ) { 
            continue; 
        }
        $product    = $item->get_product(); // Get the product object
        $product_id = $item->get_product_id(); // Get the product ID or the parent product ID

        $order_details .= "**LT**item**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**ID**GT**" . $product->get_sku() . "**LT**/ID**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**produktname**GT**" . $item->get_name() . "**LT**/produktname**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**amount**GT**" . $item->get_quantity() . "**LT**/amount**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**upload**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'upload', $product_id ) ) . "**LT**/upload**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**size**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'size', $product_id ) ) . "**LT**/size**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**groesse**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'produktgröße', $product_id ) )  . "**LT**/groesse**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**material**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'material', $product_id ) ) . "**LT**/material**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**print**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'print', $product_id ) ) . "**LT**/print**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**variante**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'variante', $product_id ) ) . "**LT**/variante**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**category**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'category', $product_id ) ) . "**LT**/category**GT**";

        //add options to the output
        $order_details .= "**LT**Options**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**Option**GT****LT**ID**GT**" . "1996" . "**LT**/ID**GT****LT**Value**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'value_115', $product_id ) ) . "**LT**/Value**GT****LT**/Option**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**Option**GT****LT**ID**GT**" . "2489" . "**LT**/ID**GT****LT**Value**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'value_117', $product_id ) ) . "**LT**/Value**GT****LT**/Option**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**Option**GT****LT**ID**GT**" . "2056" . "**LT**/ID**GT****LT**Value**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'value_118', $product_id ) ) . "**LT**/Value**GT****LT**/Option**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**/Options**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**/item**GT**";
    }
    return $order_details;
}

Now the ACF fields should no more be empty on variable products.

Hello @loictheaztec
Great, that helps. Thanks.
One thing is missing:
How can I query and display the size of ordered variable products?
E.g. a T-SHIRT (variable product) is ordered in size M:
M
This information is still missing in XML output.
Sizes of the variable products are created as ‘attribute’ GROESSE in Woocommerce.
This information is currently retrieved here:
$order_details .= ‘LTgroesseGT’ . maybe_serialise( get_field( ‘product_size’, $product_id ) ) . ‘LT/groesseGT’;
Maybe you have an idea? Thank you.

Sorry, I’am really new here..... I’ve created a new question concerning this size problem. New Question. Maybe you have an idea. Many thanks.
